# powershell -- copy filename insert same filename to the top line of the file

Tags: powershell, file, insert, filenames

I recently started using PowerShell and found some nifty tricks (thank you stacko) for adding text to each file in a folder. Pretty cool indeed. But now instead of inserting text as markers to each file, how would one copy the filename itself and paste it as the first line of the file, and do the same for all the files in that folder? Thank you.

`C:\Users\name\Documents\folder1\> get-childitem -filter "*.txt" | foreach {"r n---beginning---" + (get-content $_.fullname -raw) | out-file $_.fullname }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to replace `` "`r`n---beginning---" `` for the name of your file.

Here is an example:

```
Get-ChildItem *.txt | Foreach-Object {
    "---- {0} ----`n" -f $_.Name + (Get-Content $_ -Raw) |
    Out-File $_
}
```

This will insert the `Name` of the file at the top like this:

```
---- fileName.txt ----
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit....
......
......
```

Comment: OMG! That is beautiful. It worked perfectly. Thank you so much.

Comment: @nin-j no problem! glad to help :)